# Is there a method for getting the timezone_type ? (CakePHP 3.x)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

To get the timezone_type, I can use:

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;    
$now = Time::now();

$type = get_object_vars($now->timezone)['timezone_type'];
// or
$type = $now->getOffset()/60/60;
```

But is there a more correct solution in СакеPHP 3.x ?

Comment: What do you think `timezone_type` actually is/represents? Your `getOffset()` example makes me think that you're looking for something different, and that you're asking an [**xy-problem question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: No, I need to get exactly the value of the property timezone_type

Comment: But your `getOffset()` example doesn't do that, so I'd again ask what you think `timezone_type` is, and what you need it for? There is no direct way to access it, hence you'll get better help if you describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: When a user on my site makes a request for a password change (if he forgot it), then I send a letter specifying the time of such a request and the time zone. That's why I need it.

Comment: You have a `Time` object. Look at [date and time formatting](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#formatting), and find a format that includes the time zone information that you want. The (ICU page about formats)[http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details] includes a whole section on time zones.

Answer (score 0):

As a result, my decision was reduced to the following:

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;    
$now = Time::now();
$res = $now->format('d.m.Y в G:i:s').' UTC'. $now->format('O ') . $now->timezoneName;
```